# Handlebars.js and markup, retaining escaping

Tags: javascript, html, templates, web-applications, handlebars.js

I'd like to use Handlebars.js to display user-generated (read: unclean) text. In a stroke of genius Handlebars.js defaults to escaping template input. Users, however, like **rich** *markup*.

It should not be hard to first do the normal thing when using the double stashes ( '{{}}' ), but afterwards "upgrade" markup to HTML elements like < b > or < i >. Things can get finicky, and take some time, so I'd prefer an existing solution over making it myself.

Is there existing functionality to do this? If so, where? I can't seem to find it.

If there isn't, what would be a neat way to implement this?

Comment: does {{{}}} triple brackets not do what you want?

Comment: Nope, that just dumps plain HTML. I want to escape all HTML, and translate markup to HTML that doesn't get escaped. And I would really like to template that something like {{markup textVariableName}}.

Comment: ah yep right get your question now